# Accessing Windows computers in ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows

In my college all the computers are connected with lan.  Almost all other computers have windows installed. However I am using ubuntu 14.04.

I am not able to access the share files/folder which is shared on LAN.

I am not even able to see which computers are connected to LAN.

Like in windows when we click network... we can share files and copy files from the computers connected to lan.

is there a way to do same in Ubuntu?

Comment: in files, try clicking "Browse Network" on the left

Comment: Follow this http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-access-windows-7-shared-folders-ubuntu

Comment: Is samba installed?

Comment: yes samba is installed... :( @wb9688

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Ubuntu the same way you do it in Windows:

Start your file browser.  The default one is Nautilus.  You'll see a file folder at the top of the launch bar.

Click on `Browse Network`.

There you should see the various computer servers that have shared resources.  Click on the desired server, then click on the desired resource.  Answer the login criteria and you're in.

Comment: No there are two problems...

1. I am not able to see all the computers.

2. the one which I can see are not opening.